# Orchard CMS strategy for business app

Tags: e-commerce, orchardcms

This might be a big question, but I am trying to get some starting points for working with Orchard CMS. I followed some tutorials, but I didnt find the solution yet.

Case:

My web application is about selling stuff, so basically it's an ecommerce site. My first hurdle are the user profiles. I want the user object to be extended with properties like first name, etc. But I want those fields to be stored in my custom table. Rather then using the Profile Module, where the added fields are stored as content items and I cant find them back in the database.

The second hurdle is then to connect the user object to purchases. I know how to create an MVC app for creating purchase records. But I want those purchases tied to the user. So when I go into the dashboard and I click on User I should be able to see all his purchases.

I have many other hurdles, but if I can fix this, the rest will be a piece of cake (I hope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best answered with following the blog on [http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-1][1]

This is the one of the best starting points for deep diving into Orchard.